# Is there a way to stop class instances from calling each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, garbage-collection, instance

I have  multiple class instances that call each other's functions. I also have a system that detects if these functions call each other for too long (to avoid stack overflow). However, when it detects that, there's nothing it can do to actually stop them, so they just keep running until they reach recursion limit. Here's a simpler example:

```py
class test: 
    def activateOther(self, other):
        sleep(2)
        print('Activated Other Function', id(self))
        other.activateOther(self)

t = test()
t_ = test()
t.activateOther(t_)

del t, t_  # Even after deleting the variables/references, they continue running
```

Is there a way to actually stop these functions from running endlessly and hitting the recursion limit? If not, I suppose I'll try to add a variable to each class indicating whether they should continue running or not.

Comment: You'd have a "base case" in the `activateOther` function that prevents further recursive calls. This example is too contrived though to give an example of how you'd do that though.

Comment: Why does `activateOther` have an unconditional recursive call? The recursion limit issue is really just a symptom of a program design that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, `del t, t_` won't be reached. Objects aren't threads - `t` won't go off and run its `activateOther` method on its own while you continue on to `del t, t_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is a typical recursion issue. There must be a condition in the code for when the recursion is stopped. The easiest is to introduce a depth parameter:

```
class test: 
    def activateOther(self, other, depth=0):
        if depth > 88:
            return
        sleep(2)
        print('Activated Other Function', id(self))
        other.activateOther(self, depth + 1)

t = test()
t_ = test()
t.activateOther(t_)
```

The actual condition, and whether the `depth` counter will do, depends of course on your application.

Comment: There are very few cases where an arbitrary depth limit is the way to go, though. We really need to know why these methods are calling each other in the first place.